# How to make a put request in Nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, mongodb-query

I'm writing a put  method in node js and i have an error when i want to save the post it shows me an error.

```
Post.findOne({'imei.modele': req.query.modele, test: { $exists: true } })

 .then((posts) => {
   console.log(posts);
posts=aa;
posts.save().then(posts=>{
  res.json('bonjour');
})
 })


});
```

I get the following error - TypeError: `posts.save is not a function`
The request.find works correctly and the req.body is also good
so i need some help and thank you

Comment: i have a big req.BODy i want to update all the posts there is a solution for this

Comment: Why do you reassign the posts with aa ??? `posts=aa`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello it's obvious to have this behavior because you re-assign the value of `posts` with aa :

remove this

```
posts=aa;
```

Try like this

```
Post.findOne({'imei.modele': req.query.modele, test: { $exists: true } })

 .then((posts) => {
   console.log(posts);
posts.save().then(posts=>{
  res.json('bonjour');
})
 })


});
```

if you want to edit `posts` before save try something like this

Post.findOne({'imei.modele': req.query.modele, test: { $exists: true } })

```
 .then((posts) => {
   console.log(posts);
posts.modele = 'updated model'
posts.save().then(posts=>{
  res.json('bonjour');
})
 })


});
```

where this like `posts.modele = 'updated modele'` should update `modele` property

### Cleaner way

```
Post.findOneAndUpdate({'imei.modele': req.query.modele, test: { $exists: true } }, { $set : { req.body } }).then(doc=>{
      res.json('success');
    })
```

Comment: i have a big req.BODy i want to update all the posts there is a solution for this

Comment: try `Post.findOneAndUpdate({'imei.modele': req.query.modele, test: { $exists: true } }, { $set : { req.body } })`